# How can I distribute my objective c library with source code embedded

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I would like for people to be able to debug my library, should they feel like they want to.

For this I think a good idea would be to embed the source in the library / framework itself. Does Xcode support this option?

For reference of what I’m looking for, in Java you can build a Jar file which comes with the attached source code (and optional javadoc) embedded within the library https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064833/48062

Answer (score 1):

Xcode does not support this option, no.  Your best bet would be to upload the source to Github (https://github.com) and include the link in your documentation for the framework.  That way you can be sure that your users can always get to the freshest, most up to date, code.

Comment: I would also consider looking into something like CocoaPods. This way people can easily pull your code into their projects.